# Tool for reformatting reST file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I maintain a pretty large set of technical documents in restructured text.  I try to keep the line length to 80 cols so that the text is easy to diff in source control.  My problem is that over the years my paragraphs are a mess, and I end up having to spend some time with a text editor re-wrapping all the lines so short are full again.  Does anyone know of a tool that can automate this process? I tried some sed-fu, but it got tripped on headings and the indents needed to preserve formatting of lists.  It also ate my tables for lunch. Really I need something to fill short lines and fold long lines.